# Unable to run the auto complete code

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I copied this below code from the [Jquery](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#example-1). when I try to run this code on my system nothing is performing, Do I have to change anything in the scripts in header tag?

Below is the code which I copied:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autocomplete demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete"> 
<script>
var tags = [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

I new to Jquery, I am unaware of inheriting the script file in the header, can you also explain how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: are you running it from a webserver or directly using a file? I think the problem is the resource protocol for jQuery and UI files. If you are running it from a html file loaded directly from file system(in the location bar, the page url will start with `file://`) then it won't work

Comment: try changing all 3 `//code.jquery.com` to `https://code.jquery.com`

Comment: did you mean `https://code.jquery.com`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I changed it, but it is still not working.

Comment: @RajaShekar see the update it should be `https://code.jquery.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, though 1 possibility is the use of relative protocol to include the jQuery and jQuery UI resources.

If you are loading your html page using file protocol(the page url in the addressbar starts with `file://`) not using a web protocol like `http` or `https` then the system will not be able to find the remote resources. Thus the loading of jQuery and UI will fail causing the script to fail in the page.

Instead you can try to load the external resources by specifying the complete uri like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```